# Can I launch a popup from master-page to keep it open across all pages? Or where exactly should it be for the purpose?

Tags: c#, css

My requirement is to keep a chat window open across pages of my website, whatever the users do on the parent page, like refreshing or reloading the page or postbacks by controls. Please explain with code, how I can achieve this. Unless the user closes the chat window, it should remain open always, irrespective of navigation on parent page.

Comment: Please add some more detail and show us what you have tried. You may want to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Create two webpages.  One for parent and then one for child.  The child will stay open even if the parent goes to new URL.

Comment: That is not possible using a “classic” setup, where “navigation” simply means loading a completely different page. You will have to either use frames, or make the whole navigation not load new pages any more, but only load the content in the background via AJAX and then switch it out inside the current page the user is on.

Comment: Can anyone show me an example of how to use frames for showing popup with necessary CSS if required? I have tried some, but no use. Please share all necessary code changes that work together. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Give fixed position to the chat box div.

```css
.chatBox{
   position:fixed;
   z-index:9999;
   display:block;
   right:0;
   bottom:0; // chat box will place in bottom right corner of your window
   opacity:1;
   visibility:visible;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give your `div` a fixed position and placement using css. Also give a higher `z-index` to display it over everything.
In my example css, it'll place your `chat-box` div at the `bottom-right` corner.

Try this

```
.chat-box{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; // Place Bottom
    right: 0; // Place right
    z-index: 10000; //Put Higher Value
}
```